# How to compile *.ins files in TeXstudio

Tags: compiling

I am using TeXstudio and I am having difficulty in compiling `elsarticle.ins` and `elsarticle.dtx` files. Does anyone have any inputs on solving this?

Comment: Why not install the package with the package manager of your distribution?

Comment: TeXStudio is *not* a compiler. You have to type the command 'latex elsarticle.ins' in a command interpreter (eg CMD, Powershell..)

Comment: a .ins file is just a tex file so you can treat it as any other tex file either on the commandline or in an editor, but elsarticle is in texlive and miktex you should not need to install it from source.

Answer (score 1):

TeXStudio has its default configuration (Options->Configure TeXStudio->Commands) to execute only .tex files.

This is done in the 4 commands (for LaTeX, PdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX) by using the special char %, for the name of the file, and .tex.

If you change this to  ?me it will compile (m means name, e means extension).

[image: how it shows for me]

In my case, since it is configured to -interaction=nonstopmode I must delete de .sty file, or LaTeX will ask to overwrite it and the compilation will stop.

It will also work for the .dtx file, or any other file opened in your editor.

Comment: I found this question while looking for a solution. It took months, but I hope it is still useful to someone.